# Json server Data is not Fetching Correctly in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, urlfetch, json-server

I have tried to fetch data from my Local json server.

`const {data, pending, error} = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs');`

this works correctly. but i tried to fetch the data inside the blogs,

`const { data: blog, error , pending} = UseFetch(`http://localhost:8000/blogs/${id}`);`

this code snippet doesn't work correctly. When I run this code this runs like this. This server Address is not working.

`http://localhost:3000/blogs/%201` It come "%201" to the end of the address. but my content "id=1" .

when I type to address `http://localhost:3000/blogs/1` my code is working.

I am looking for a help. Check my [Repository](https://github.com/Dimuthu-10/blog-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove spaces from to="/pathname"

```
 <Link to={`/blogs/ ${blogs.id} `}>
     <h2 className='header'>{ blogs.title }</h2>
          <p>Written by { blogs.author } </p>
  </Link>
```

To this

```
<Link to={`/blogs/${blogs.id}`}>
     <h2 className='header'>{ blogs.title }</h2>
          <p>Written by { blogs.author } </p>
  </Link>
```

Comment: your answer was really helpful. now it is working correctly. There was a just simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch trying to escape some characters in api address so `encodeURI(' 1')` will be `'%201'`.

Check value of `blog.id`, it should be number, not string.